# Android app which uses my phone's mic and accelerometer to help me learn how well I slept

Tags: gratis, android, health

### Introduction

I have a Samsung Galaxy S Relay cellphone running Android 4.1.2.

For quite a while, I've been using SleepBot to keep track of my sleep.

### What is SleepBot?

SleepBot is an app which offers, among other features, "sleep tracking". It uses my phone's mic and accelerometer to keep track of noise and movement while I sleep. I can then wake up, look at the graphs, and estimate how much time I actually spent sleeping (instead of just tossing and turning).

The app also includes a "sleep debt" calculation feature, although researchers disagree regarding whether or not the concept of sleep debt describes a measurable phenomenon.

The app is still freeware and still downloadable from the Google Play store. But the app's product manager has made it known that development has ceased. No features will ever be added, and no bugs will ever be fixed.

(You can read more about SleepBot [here](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SleepBot).)

### What I'd like

I'm looking for an app which, like SleepBot, can:

1. Keep track of motion, and
2. Keep track of sound levels.

### Some choices I've looked into already

Here are some apps I think I might not choose:

Not SleepBot, because it's unmaintained and buggier than I'd like.

Not [ElectricSleep](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.androsz.electricsleepbeta).  It's free and open source, but [can't monitor sound levels](//code.google.com/p/electricsleep/issues/detail?id=123).  Patches are welcome.  :)

Probably not [Azumio Sleep Time](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.azumio.android.sleeptime).  On other OSes, things might be different, but on Android, it's unclear to me whether or not it can monitor sound levels.  Plus:  The [free version](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.azumio.android.sleeptime) is popular but unmaintained.  It appears that the [paid version](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.azumio.android.sleeptime.paid) is still maintained but is not very popular.

And maybe not [Sleep as Android](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.urbandroid.sleep).  It isn't quite free.  The full free-trial period lasts only two weeks; after the two-week period ends, its sleep-tracking functionality will only work for [three nights a week](https://sites.google.com/site/sleepasandroid/get-support/q-a-faq#trialexpires) unless you buy an unlock code.    I'd rather choose a free app.

### Conclusion

Could you please suggest something which is either still-maintained (so that I can send in bug reports) or else mostly bug-free?

P.S.  This question still could use some more copyediting.  If you could edit and improve it, or even if you could simply comment, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: I've got no experience with any of them, but you might wish to take a look at my list of [Alarm Clocks with Sleep Monitoring](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/multimedia_alarmclocks#group_361) for some alternatives.

Comment: @Izzy: Intriguing! Not all the words are in English. What do "Vorstellung" and "Testbericht" mean? Still, thank you for the link. The ["Alarm clocks for sleep phases"](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/multimedia_alarmclocks#group_360) list might also be useful.

Comment: If the "words" are in English, the text behind the link is as well. If they are not, nor is the text (the two terms you've mentioned point to a German intro and test/review). So in short: if the words mean nothing to you, you don't need to follow the link (or should open it with Google Translator ;) And glad you like my site :)

Comment: Sleep Cycle seems like an app you might be interested in. It doesn't use the microphone but it uses your phone's accelerometer to measure how much you move throughout the night. They consider less movement as being in a deeper sleep and so on. It is a paid app.

Comment: Hi Bry; thanks to you, you've inspired me to further edit my question in order to better clarify it. I see you write that Sleep Cycle doesn't use the microphone at all. Does it have any major advantages over Sleep as Android?

Comment: For people passing by his question; you may want to look into fitness watches and the like. Even the really cheap ones measure sleep well.